# circles inside a square: algorithm

Tags: math, automation

I have a square of 14 x 14 km. And I need to place around 233 circles of radius 1km inside them, assuming circles can overlap to adjacent circle until 30% of its area. Also there should be no space uncovered. Currently my matlab code using random alignment of the circles could produce around 135 circles. Can anybody suggest an algorithm or suggest any ways to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *At least* 233, or *exactly* 233?

Comment: How can you have no space uncovered?  I think that the corners must have some space uncovered, since you can't pack circles into the corner without leaving the boundary.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sorry for the confusion. Its exactly 233.

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes,sorry again, I agree with you that the corners can remain uncovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked to place circles whose combined area is 731 square km inside a space of 196 square km.  Even allowing 30% overlaps, this is impossible.

That said, if you're looking for a dense packing of circles, the hexagonal packing is always a good default to start with.  Think of a honeycomb.  Or see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePacking.html for a picture of it.